# Summary and Total Invoice Data in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a complete query that can be dropped into a report displaying tool (like Crystal Reports or Report Writer).

I've almost got this working, but I can't seem to get the **Grand Totals** row on the bottom.

SQL Fiddle would not build this table, saying there is insufficient memory. (???) So, all I can do is paste it here.

Here is my sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jp2Invoice](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceNumber] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Subtotal] [decimal](9, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Taxable] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [TaxRate] [decimal](9, 4) NULL,
    [TaxableAmount] [decimal](9, 4) NOT NULL,
    [NontaxableAmount] [decimal](9, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Tax] [decimal](9, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Total] [decimal](9, 4) NOT NULL,
    [AmountTendered] [decimal](9, 4) NOT NULL,
    [ChangeAmount] [decimal](9, 4) NOT NULL,
    [AmountDue] [decimal](9, 4) NOT NULL,
    [ChargeAmount] [decimal](9, 4) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_jp2Invoice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is some sample data to go in it:

```
insert into jp2Invoice(
  InvoiceNumber, Subtotal, Taxable, TaxRate, TaxableAmount, NontaxableAmount, Tax, Total, AmountTendered, ChangeAmount, AmountDue, ChargeAmount
) values 
('ABC001',  19.9500, 'Y', 8.2500,  19.9500,   0.0000,  1.6458,  21.5958,  40.0000, 18.4041,   0.0000,   0.0000),
('ABC002', 558.8300, 'Y', 6.0000, 335.3000, 223.5300, 20.1180, 355.4180,   0.0000,  0.0000,   0.0000, 355.4180),
('ABC003', 281.4700, 'Y', 8.2500, 281.4700,   0.0000, 23.2212, 304.6912,   0.0000,  0.0000,   0.0000, 304.6913),
('ABC004',  95.9800, 'Y', 8.2500,  95.9800,   0.0000,  7.9183, 103.8983,   0.0000,  0.0000,   0.0000, 103.8983),
('ABC005',  73.1900, 'Y', 8.2500,  73.1900,   0.0000,  6.0381,  79.2281, 100.0000, 20.7718,   0.0000,   0.0000),
('ABC006', 215.6500, 'N', 0.0000,   0.0000, 215.6500,  0.0000, 215.6500,   0.0000,  0.0000,   0.0000, 215.6500),
('ABC007', 146.0200, 'Y', 8.2500, 146.0200,   0.0000, 12.0466, 158.0666,   0.0000,  0.0000,   0.0000, 158.0667);
```

With that data, I have created this query:

```
select
 case when ChargeAmount=0 then 'Cash' else 'Charge' end as 'TxType',
 TaxRate,
 sum(Subtotal) as 'SubTotal',
 sum(TaxableAmount) as 'TaxAmt',
 sum(AmountTendered) as 'Tendered',
 sum(ChangeAmount) as 'Change',
 sum(ChargeAmount) as 'Charged',
 sum(Total) as 'Total'
from jp2Invoice
group by case when ChargeAmount=0 then 'Cash' else 'Charge' end,
 TaxRate
```

That query produces the following table:

```
TxType TaxRate  SubTotal      TaxAmt    Tendered     Change  Charged    Total
Charge  0.0000  215.6500      0.0000      0.0000     0.0000 215.6500    215.6500
Charge  6.0000  558.8300    335.3000      0.0000     0.0000 355.4180    355.4180
Cash    8.2500   93.1400     93.1400    140.0000    39.1759   0.0000    100.8239
Charge  8.2500  523.4700    523.4700      0.0000     0.0000 566.6563    566.6561
```

First: It looks like that table is grouping first by the TaxRate, and then by the "TxType", even though the **group by** clause shows the "TxType" calculation coming first. How do I force the "Cash" to come first and the "Charge" to come next?

Second: How would I write a **Grand Total** row at the bottom with the calculations showing the totals? I have hand calculated one in the sample table below:

```
TxType TaxRate  SubTotal      TaxAmt    Tendered     Change  Charged    Total
Charge  0.0000  215.6500      0.0000      0.0000     0.0000  215.6500    215.6500
Charge  6.0000  558.8300    335.3000      0.0000     0.0000  355.4180    355.4180
Cash    8.2500   93.1400     93.1400    140.0000    39.1759    0.0000    100.8239
Charge  8.2500  523.4700    523.4700      0.0000     0.0000  566.6563    566.6561
Totals         1391.0900    951.91      140.0000    39.1759 1137.7243   1238.5480
```

There could be some typos in that because it was all hand edited.

How would I get the data to display first by TxType and show a Totals row on the bottom?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use WITH ROLLUP to get a totals row and use ORDER BY to order your rows.  You can also use GROUPING() to add a 'TOTALS' label.

```
select
 CASE WHEN GROUPING(case when ChargeAmount=0 then 'Cash' else 'Charge' end) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE case when ChargeAmount=0 then 'Cash' else 'Charge' end END as 'TxType',
 TaxRate,
 sum(Subtotal) as 'SubTotal',
 sum(TaxableAmount) as 'TaxAmt',
 sum(AmountTendered) as 'Tendered',
 sum(ChangeAmount) as 'Change',
 sum(ChargeAmount) as 'Charged',
 sum(Total) as 'Total'
from jp2Invoice
group by case when ChargeAmount=0 then 'Cash' else 'Charge' end,
 TaxRate WITH ROLLUP

ORDER BY case when ChargeAmount=0 then 'Cash' else 'Charge' end
```

Comment: Better answer than `Union ALL`

Comment: This will also add subtotals for the TxTyp. You can avoid those with: `HAVING GROUPING(case when ChargeAmount=0 then 'Cash' else 'Charge' end) = GROUPING(TaxRate)` and then adding to the `ORDER BY` to make sure that the total goes at the end of the results. There might be a more elegant way, than comparing the `GROUPING` values, but I didn't think of one immediately.

Comment: You can also use a CTE to grab the results from the query above and then ISNULL the NULL values to make them blanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION ALL`

```
select
 case when ChargeAmount=0 then 'Cash' else 'Charge' end as 'TxType',
 TaxRate,
 sum(Subtotal) as 'SubTotal',
 sum(TaxableAmount) as 'TaxAmt',
 sum(AmountTendered) as 'Tendered',
 sum(ChangeAmount) as 'Change',
 sum(ChargeAmount) as 'Charged',
 sum(Total) as 'Total'
from jp2Invoice
group by case when ChargeAmount=0 then 'Cash' else 'Charge' end, TaxRate
UNION ALL
select
'Totals',
NULL,
sum(Subtotal) as 'SubTotal',
sum(TaxableAmount) as 'TaxAmt',
sum(AmountTendered) as 'Tendered',
sum(ChangeAmount) as 'Change',
sum(ChargeAmount) as 'Charged',
sum(Total) as 'Total'
from jp2Invoice
```