# SQL Add row of Total from a current column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Trying to add a summary row of Grand Totals from the existing Weekly_Total column - (this is coming from a temp table,not that that matters) -

```
SELECT
Rep, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Weekly_Total
FROM #bl_reptemp3
```

Which returns:
[image: these results]

and I just want to add one row under Weekly_Total, with a sum of thhat column - can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583753/summary-and-total-invoice-data-in-sql-query/35583968#35583968

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a summary row with totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934318/add-a-summary-row-with-totals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT
Rep, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Weekly_Total
FROM #bl_reptemp3

UNION

SELECT
Null Rep, Null Monday, NULL Tuesday, Null Wednesday, Null Thursday, NULL Friday, 
SUM(Weekly_Total) Weekly_Total
FROM #bl_reptemp3
```

Comment: Guess u haven't understood required OP, Op wants a Weekly_total Column as output

Comment: @Ven OP wants a row.

Comment: @bvmcode, thanks so much, that works, I never understood UNION.

Comment: What...? You asked how to insert a row that has a total of a column. And you're marking an answer that doesn't do that.. ?

Comment: @Nerdi.org he wants a blank row, and just a sum of the weekly column.

Comment: Yeah... INSERT INTO table (weekly_total) SELECT SUM(weekly_total)... It's a one liner.

Comment: ...You ASKED how to INSERT a row. The answer told you how to SELECT information. I don't see how this answer differs from any of the others. You should have clarified you didn't need to insert data into an actual table. You said temp table, so I took that as being you want to insert data into a table that you will eventually delete. It sounds more like you just needed a SELECT query to show the data within your DB gui. In the future please try to clarify these things if you can

Comment: "add a row to my result" is not the same thing as INSERT into the table, I didn't ask for INSERT, I asked how to add a total row, and the accepted answer did exactly that, perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(columnName)
```

is how you get a total of a column

So...

```
INSERT INTO table (columns, go, here) SELECT 'value', 'val', SUM(here) FROM table
```

You just need a simple INSERT SELECT statement.

Comment: INSERT INTO table (column) SELECT SUM(column) FROM table

Comment: Everything I've told you is enough for you to do what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use `Aggregate` here, simply add columns

```
Select Rep, Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,
         Monday+Tuesday+Wednesday+Thursday+Friday As weekly_total
from Mytable
```

In case you have null values in column

```
use isnull(monday,0)
```

Comment: Your addition would produce a weekly_total column which OP already has.

Comment: Highlighting Op's requirement `I just want to add one row under Weekly_Total, with a sum of thhat column`

Comment: @m21 Can u please clarify what is your required output as sample data

Comment: Mhmm... INSERT SELECT... With sum(column). Y'all are overcomplicating it

Answer (score -2):

The way to add total rows in SQL Server is to use `WITH ROLLUP`. It doesn't look like your query is doing any aggregations, so you might need to add it to your query that is populating the temp table.

```
SELECT some_value, SUM(some_other_value) AS summed_value
FROM your_table
GROUP BY some_value
WITH ROLLUP
```